# Print array content in console log

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array that contains data from a json file , and i want to print its values in console, what is the solution

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.users.getusers().subscribe(data => this.UsersList = data);
  console.console(this.UsersList );

}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(this.UsersList );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it inside the subscribe callback function

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.users.getusers().subscribe(function(data){
         this.UsersList = data;
        console.log(this.UsersList );
      }.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: Nice catch btw.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.dir(this.UsersList);
```

or

```
console.log(this.UsersList );
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.users.getusers()` must be an asynchronous method because of which we have used subscribe method on the returned Observable, and the function passed into the subscribe method is executed when `getUsers()` result is returned after making a asynchronous call. Line : `console.console(this.UsersList );` is executed before subsribe method, but we want to console after our userlist is updated. So put this line inside subscribe method, and this will be executed after updating the userList.
Also, use `console.log` instead of `console.console`

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.users.getusers().subscribe(data => {
      this.UsersList = data;
      console.log(this.UsersList);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not console.console , it is console.log and place it within subscribe

```
 this.users.getusers().subscribe(
   data => this.UsersList = data;
   console.log(this.UsersList);
);
```

Comment: Did you check your answer? This code won't even compile, and recommendation to "place within `subscribe`" is somewhat confusing, since in fact the call is inside callback.